# Which custom key bindings do you use in Vim?

Tags: vim

Which custom key bindings do you use to increase productivity in Vim?

My two favorites are:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>

" Clear screen clears search highlighting.
nnoremap <C-L> :nohl<CR><C-L>
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/what-are-your-favorite-vim-tricks

Comment: At the very least this needs to be a community wiki.

Answer (score 4):

### Window Management

```
" Window splitting
nmap <silent> <leader>sh :leftabove vnew<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>sl :rightbelow vnew<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>sk :leftabove new<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>sj :rightbelow new<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>swh :topleft vnew<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>swl :botright vnew<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>swk :topleft new<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>swj :botright new<cr>

" Scroll the window next to the current one
" (especially useful for two-window splits)
nmap <silent> <leader>j <c-w>w<c-d><c-w>W
nmap <silent> <leader>k <c-w>w<c-u><c-w>W
```

### Text Editing

```
" Toggle search highlighting
nmap <silent> <leader>/ :set hlsearch!<cr>
" Toggle paste mode
" (prefer this over 'pastetoggle' to echo the current state)
nmap <leader>p :setlocal paste! paste?<cr>

" Select the last edited (or pasted) text
nmap gv `[v`]

" Keep lines that do (or do not) contain the last search term
nmap <leader>v/ :v/<c-r>//d<cr>gg
nmap <leader>g/ :g/<c-r>//d<cr>gg

" Email (de-)quotation
nmap <leader>q vip:s/^/> /<cr>
vmap <leader>q :s/^/> /<cr>
nmap <leader>Q vip:s/^> //<cr>
vmap <leader>Q :s/^> //<cr>
```

### File Opening and Saving

```
" Save and restore session
nmap <leader>ss :wa<cr>:mksession! $HOME/.vim/sessions/
nmap <leader>rs :wa<cr>:source $HOME/.vim/sessions/

" Write buffer through sudo
cnoreabbrev w!! w !sudo tee % >/dev/null

" Change the current directory to the directory of the file in buffer
nmap <silent> <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>:pwd<cr>

" Open file located in the same directory as the current one
nmap <leader>e :e <c-r>=expand('%:p:h').'/'<cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Grep the word under cursor**:

Using the following grepprg options it will search recursively into the current directory excluding and including some specific files.

```
" Quick Grep
noremap <Leader>g :grep<space><C-r><C-w><CR>:copen<CR><CR><C-W>b

set grepprg=grep\ -nH
\\--include='*.c'
\\--include='*.cpp'
\\--include='*.h'
\\--exclude-dir='.svn'
\\--exclude='*.svn-base'
\\--exclude-dir='OBJ'
\\--exclude='symTbl.c'
\\ $*
\\ -R\ .
```

It greps the word under cursor, then open the Quickfix Window and move the cursor to the bottow window (which should be the list of grep results)

This is probably one of the shortcut I use the most, and it saves lots of typing !

**Moving around quickly between windows**

```
noremap <C-j> <C-W>j
noremap <C-k> <C-W>k
noremap <C-h> <C-W>h
noremap <C-l> <C-W>l
```

It is quite intuitive and handy to move around when your screen is split horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Looks like quick grep is missing something. You're not searching a file! `:grep <C-r><C-w> <C-r>%<CR>:copen<CR><CR><C-W>b`

Comment: @pydave : you are absolutely right, the reason why I have not included the file is that it is defined in my `grepprg` options. I will update my message accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The following command remaps `;` to `:` in command mode, saving you from wasting precious milliseconds holding and releasing the Shift key when typing commands like `:wq`:

```
" Remap ";" to ":"
map ; :
noremap ;; ;
```

If you need to type an actual `;`, just press it twice.

Comment: This one conflicts with `f`/`F` search

Comment: I map semicolon to colon, and colon to semicolon. You use commands way more than the f/F functionality, though you still have the ability to access it the way I use it.

Answer (score 2):

**Insert mode**

```
" <esc> in normal mode clears highlight
nnoremap <silent> <esc> :noh<cr><esc>
```

**Command Line Editing**

```
" copy an entire word from the line above instead of just one
inoremap <expr> <c-y> matchstr(getline(line('.')-1), '\%' . 
\ virtcol('.') . 'v\%(\k\+\\|.\)')

" Insert Directory of current buffer and open completion
cnoremap <expr> <c-k> getcmdline()[getcmdpos()-2] == " " ? 
\ expand("%:h") .  "/\<c-d>" : "\<c-d>"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let mapleader=","

" omnicompletion : words
inoremap <leader>, <C-x><C-o>

" omnicompletion : filepaths
inoremap <leader>: <C-x><C-f>

" omnicompletion : lines
inoremap <leader>= <C-x><C-l>

" toggle TagList
nnoremap <leader>l :TlistToggle<CR>

" toggle NERDTree
nnoremap <leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" I like vertically aligned assignation operators
nnoremap <leader>a :Tabularize<Space>

" with | marking the cursor
" it turns this 
" function foo(){|}
" into this
" function foo(){
"   |
" }
inoremap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>

" push the current ligne up and down
nnoremap <M-D-Up>   ddKp
nnoremap <M-D-Down> ddP  

" swap word under the cursor with previous word on the left
" from the Vim wiki
nnoremap <M-D-Left>  "_yiw?\w\+\_W\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o><C-l>

" swap word under the cursor with next word on the right
" from the Vim wiki
nnoremap <M-D-Right> "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o>/\w\+\_W\+<CR><C-l>

" and I have lusty-explorers "modes" mapped to:
" "files"   <leader>f
" "buffers" <leader>b
" "grep"    <leader>g
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful for navigating up/down long lines that wrap to multiple lines on your display: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys move through screen lines rather than file lines.

```
map <A-Down> gj
map <A-Up> gk
imap <A-Up> <ESC>gki
imap <A-Down> <ESC>gji
```